# How to use template helpers in meteor js?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I am working on a project which needs to get parameters from url and insert it in mongodb.I i am using the below code,which is working but still some silly issues is causing a problem.
Below is the main.js code:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Dbs } from '../lib/collects.js';
import './main.html';


Router.route('/temp1/:ppid', function () {
this.render('temp1', {
data: function () 
{
var rpms = this.params.query.rpms;
return Dbs.findOne({patient_id:this.params.ppid});    
}
});
});

Template.temp1.helpers({
  'tempr': function() {
    var p=Router.current().params.ppid;
    var path1=Router.current().params.query.path;
    var doc_id1 =Router.current().params.query.docid;
    var temp1 = Router.current().params.query.temp;
    var age1 = Router.current().params.query.age;
    var gender1= Router.current().params.query.gender;
    var height1= Router.current().params.query.height;
    var weight1= Router.current().params.query.weight;
    var tempr= Router.current().params.query.tempr;
 Meteor.call('dbs.update',p,doc_id1,path1,temp1,age1,gender1,height1,weight1,tempr); 
 }   
});

Below is main.html code:
<head>
  <title>project1</title>

   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="#c5cae9 indigo lighten-4">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
   <a href="#" class="brand-logo">A3RMT</a>
   <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
<div class="row">
<div class="col s2">
</div>
</div>
</body>

<template name="a3">
<div class="row">
      <div class="col s2">
        <h4 class="black-text text-darken-4">INFORMATION</h4>
      <table class="centered">
      <form class="sub">
       <tr>
        <td><th>Doc_ID</th>{{doc_id}}</td>
        <td><th>tempr</th>{{tempr}}</td>
        <td><th>temp</th>{{temp}}</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><th>Path</th>{{path}}</td>
        <td><th>age</th>{{age}}</td>
        <td><th>gender</th>{{gendert}}</td>
        <td><th>weight</th>{{weight}}</td>
        <td><th>Height</th>{{height}}</td>
      </tr>
</form></table></div></div>

</template>
```

The above code is working fine but the only issue is  with line of code:"'tempr': function()".When i insert new parameters from url,its values are stored in database and even updated when i do update but it does not display value of "tempr" from database.And if i change 'tempr':function() to 'abc':function() i am not able to update nor insert anything into database. I am not understanding what am i suppose to use

```
Template.temp1.helpers({
      'tempr': function() {
```

please anyone help me with this issue.How do i use template helpers 
what do i need to specify at the place of "tempr" in
Template.temp1.helpers({'tempr': function()

Comment: Why are you using a helper to make a meteor method call? The helper is used to work with data and supply it to the html dynamically. The template runs multiple times when the page loads. In your case, the ```dbs.update``` will be called many times over and over when the page loads. Ideally, any method call should be present in ```events```. Eg. when you submit the form, update the db.  If you want the update to happen each time the page loads, then have it put in the `onRendered()` method

Comment: Also, you are using a template helper for ```temp1``` but I don't see any template called ```temp1``` in the html code you've shared. I think you may need to take a further look and share only the code that is relevant to the problem you're facing.

Comment: Thank you @  blueren .you are always helpful. Solved the issue in few seconds.If you don't mind please suggest me some links to meteor tutorials so that i can learn it.

Comment: There are a ton of youtube videos, not to mention a plethora of blogs on meteor development. It all depends on what you search for. Google is your friend.

Comment: Okay sir.thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The helper is used to work with data and supply it to the html dynamically. The template runs multiple times when the page loads. In your case, the dbs.update will be called many times over and over when the page loads. Ideally, any method call should be present in events. Eg. when you submit the form, update the db. If you want the update to happen each time the page loads, then have it put in the onRendered() method.

Probable solution:

```
Templates.<<template_name>>.events({

// on submit of a form or something similar


    var p=Router.current().params.ppid;
    var path1=Router.current().params.query.path;
    var doc_id1 =Router.current().params.query.docid;
    var temp1 = Router.current().params.query.temp;
    var age1 = Router.current().params.query.age;
    var gender1= Router.current().params.query.gender;
    var height1= Router.current().params.query.height;
    var weight1= Router.current().params.query.weight;
    var tempr= Router.current().params.query.tempr;
 Meteor.call('dbs.update',p,doc_id1,path1,temp1,age1,gender1,height1,weight1,tempr); 

})
```